# how to download the preprocessed image of tesseract in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract.js

From my understanding, tesseract.js applies filters to the uploaded image before attempting  to processes it. But, the image might still be of poor quality. To make sure that the image looks good, tesseract offers an option to download the image after it's filters have been applied to it.
in the documentation  it states:

> You can see how Tesseract has processed the image by using the
> configuration variable tessedit_write_images to true

This is the issue. I can't seem to find a way to set tessedit_write_images to true. I looked everywhere on how to do this in nodejs but i couldn't find an answer.

I tried modifying the example code provided in the documentation (posted below) by adding `tessedit_write_images = true` to it but it didn't work:

```
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js');

const worker = createWorker();

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  await worker.setParameters({
    tessedit_char_whitelist: '0123456789',
    tessedit_write_images : true // added this but typescript gives an error
  });
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```